# How to transfer source code from xcode to another developer?

Tags: ios, xcode, transfer

I am wondering what the best way is to transfer an Xcode project to the new app owner after transferring the app ownership in iTunes connect. I searched everywhere for this question but I could only find information on how to do the ownership transfer in iTunes connect. I am only a few months into swift and ios app development so this will be my first time transferring an app. 
Any help would be much appreciated,
thanks.

Comment: XCode project is just files with code. Zip project folder and send it over email. New owner will be able to open it.

Comment: Use `git` to manage team working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to completely transfer ownership of an app, you have to do the following things:

1. Transfer app itself using Itunes Connect.
2. Give access to source files. If you plan to work with this project in future it's best to use git, otherwise you can just zip and send them over.
3. Export .p12 key from your keychain and send it to the new developer. This key will be needed to sign future releases of your app.

The last step is optional because you can always create a new signing cert, as long as you have access to dev. portal.

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I needed. Also what exactly does the p12 key give the other person access to?

Comment: Great, feel free to mark as correct if this helped. p12 key is required to sign your project when it's archieved, it doesn't give access to anything